# Scoping when creating a new r data.table column in a function using :=

Tags: r, data.table, scoping

This is a continuation for a question I posted here [Creating a new r data.table column based on values in another column and grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450543/creating-a-new-r-data-table-column-based-on-values-in-another-column-and-groupin), and to which @Frank provided an excellent answer.

As I have to do multiple of these calculations with different date intervals, I want to do a function which does them. However, I seem to be running into a scoping problem. I read the Vignettes, FAQ, and a ton of questions here and I still am left baffled.

We'll use the same data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(88)
DT <- data.table(date = Sys.Date()-365 + sort(sample(1:100, 10)), 
zip = sample(c("2000", "1150", "3000"),10, replace = TRUE), 
purchaseAmount = sample(1:20, 10))
```

Here is the answer @Frank provided:

```
DT[, new_col := 
  DT[.(zip = zip, d0 = date - 10, d1 = date), on=.(zip, date >= d0, date <= d1), 
    sum(purchaseAmount)
  , by=.EACHI ]$V1
]


DT 

              date  zip purchaseAmount new_col
     1: 2016-01-08 1150              5       5
     2: 2016-01-15 3000             15      15
     3: 2016-02-15 1150             16      16
     4: 2016-02-20 2000             18      18
     5: 2016-03-07 2000             19      19
     6: 2016-03-15 2000             11      30
     7: 2016-03-17 2000              6      36
     8: 2016-04-02 1150             17      17
     9: 2016-04-08 3000              7       7
    10: 2016-04-09 3000             20      27
```

And now the actual problem I have encountered. I created the following function which enables dynamically changing the interval:

```
sumPreviousPurchases = function(dt, newColName, daysFrom, daysUntil){
    zip = substitute(zip)
    newColName = substitute(newColName)
    dt[, newColName := 
        dt[.(zip = zip, d0 = (date - daysUntil), d1 = (date - daysFrom))
        , on=.(zip, date >= d0, date <= d1), 
        sum(purchaseAmount)
        , by=.EACHI ]$V1
    ]
}

sumPreviousPurchases(DT, prevPurch1to10, 0, 10)

DT

          date  zip purchaseAmount newColName
 1: 2016-02-07 1150              5          5
 2: 2016-02-14 3000             15         15
 3: 2016-03-16 1150             16         16
 4: 2016-03-21 2000             18         18
 5: 2016-04-06 2000             19         19
 6: 2016-04-14 2000             11         30
 7: 2016-04-16 2000              6         36
 8: 2016-05-02 1150             17         17
 9: 2016-05-08 3000              7          7
10: 2016-05-09 3000             20         27
```

What troubles me is the scoping. The function names the new column `newColName` regardless of what I insert in the function call. From reading I got that when calling for data.table column names in function arguments, one should use the `substitute()`-function. However, this does not work here, the result is the same even if I leave the whole `newColName = substitute(newColName)` line out. I suppose it is because the column does not exist yet, but I do not know how to address this issue.

As a bonus I would like to ask, is there also a way to name the columns dynamically, ie. in the example for instance to be "`daysFrom`_ to_`daysUntil`", and the name would be "0_to_10"?

----- EDIT ----

I also stumbled upon a possible answer myself, somewhat similarly to @lmo's answer using an idea from here: http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#assign-a-column-with--named-with-a-character-object

Most important differences on the question: I removed the `newColName = substitute(newColName)` entirely, and added brackets around the `(newColName)` on `dt[, (newColName) :=`

```
sumPreviousPurchases = function(dt, newColName, daysFrom, daysUntil){
    zip = substitute(zip)
    #newColName = substitute(newColName)
    dt[, (newColName) := 
        dt[.(zip = zip, d0 = (date - daysUntil), d1 = (date - daysFrom))
        , on=.(zip, date >= d0, date <= d1), 
        sum(purchaseAmount)
        , by=.EACHI ]$V1
    ]
}
```

Additionally I added quotes to the `"prevPurch1to10"`.

```
sumPreviousPurchases(DT, "prevPurch1to10", 0, 10)
```

and got the answer

```
          date  zip purchaseAmount prevPurch1to10
 1: 2016-02-17 1150              7              7
 2: 2016-02-22 3000              8              8
 3: 2016-03-04 1150              2              2
 4: 2016-03-16 2000             14             14
 5: 2016-04-03 2000             11             11
 6: 2016-04-11 3000             12             12
 7: 2016-04-21 1150             17             17
 8: 2016-04-22 3000              3              3
 9: 2016-05-03 2000              9              9
10: 2016-05-11 3000              4              4
```

However, there are still the two following weird things:

a) `substitute()` is not needed when adding the brackets on `(newColName)`. Why is that?

b) quotes are required around the `"prevPurch1to10"`. Again, why? Is there a more `data.table`ish way to do this, without the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use substitute directly in the assignment:

```
sumPreviousPurchases = function(dt, newColName, daysFrom, daysUntil){
    zip = substitute(zip)
    dt[, substitute(newColName) := 
           dt[.(zip = zip, d0 = (date - daysUntil), d1 = (date - daysFrom))
              , on=.(zip, date >= d0, date <= d1), 
              sum(purchaseAmount)
              , by=.EACHI ]$V1
       ]
}
```

Then give it a try

```
sumPreviousPurchases(DT, "prevPurch1to10", 0, 10)
```

which returns

```
DT
          date  zip purchaseAmount prevPurch1to10
 1: 2016-02-07 1150              5              5
 2: 2016-02-14 3000             15             15
 3: 2016-03-16 1150             16             16
 4: 2016-03-21 2000             18             18
 5: 2016-04-06 2000             19             19
 6: 2016-04-14 2000             11             30
 7: 2016-04-16 2000              6             36
 8: 2016-05-02 1150             17             17
 9: 2016-05-08 3000              7              7
10: 2016-05-09 3000             20             27
```

---

Notes:

- The parentheses in your solution `()` force the evaluation of the argument. This is implemented in base R and is a common technique across many programming languages, based on the mathematical concept of order of operations. (first evaluate objects in parentheses, then exponetiate, etc.). The use of `substitute` makes the substitution explicit, perhaps for easier reading.
- Often, an argument to a function that will define a future object, like prevPurch1to10, requires quotes, since the object does not exist prior to calling the function. Using such an argument without quotes will usually result in an error: "object X not found."

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I also added my own answer, because the `substitute` does not seem to be necessary, and you also added the quotes around the `"prevPurch1to10"`, the necessity of which I do not understand.